# How to access mapping array and address of contract in truffle test

Tags: truffle-test, solidity-0.5.x

I have 3 contracts: sender, receiver and transferTest. I am getting error in transferTest due to an address array declared in the reciver contract:

receiver.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract receiver{
   address public owner;
   mapping(address => uint) balance; 
constructor () public{
   owner = msg.sender;
}
function() external payable{
   balance[owner] += msg.value;}
}
```

transferTest:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/sender.sol";
import "../contracts/receiver.sol";

contract TestTransfer{

   function testTransfer() public{
      sender senderObj = new sender();
      receiver receiverObj = new receiver();
      senderObj.transferTo(msg.sender, 10);
      Assert.equal(receiver.balance[receiver.owner], 9, "Received amount is not correct");
   }
}
```

I am getting following error message:

> testingTransfer.sol:12:20: TypeError: Member "balance" not found or
> not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract
> receiver).
> Assert.equal(receiver.balance[receiver.owner], 9, "Received amount is not correct");
> ^--------------^
>
> Compilation failed. See above. Truffle v5.1.67 (core: 5.1.67) Node
> v10.23.3

Also I used msg.sender for the address of receiver contract as the first argument of transferTo function. Please guide me how to replace msg.sender with the address of receiver contract.
==Update:Dec11 2021
My question is similar to:
[Accessing Solidity Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213842/how-to-access-solidity-mapping-which-has-value-of-array-type)

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `balancew` isn't public so it can't be accessed from the outside

```
mapping(address => uint) balance;
```

If it were public you would be able to access like a function with the keys as parameters.

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;
```

From truffle's console

```
> let allow = await token.allowance("0x1234..", "0x4444...")
```

---

A fixed version of `TestTransfer` should look like

```
contract TestTransfer {

   function testTransfer() public{
      sender senderObj = new sender();
      receiver receiverObj = new receiver();
      senderObj.transferTo(msg.sender, 10);
      Assert.equal(receiverObj.balance(receiverObj.owner()), 9, "Received amount is not correct");
   }
}
```

Comment: Kindly suggest me answer for Assert.equal(...) statement in the context of truffle test.

Comment: I made the balance public but same error.

Comment: @zak100 I haven't tried but `Assert.equal(receiver.balance(receiver.owner()), 9, "...");` should work if `owner` is a public variable in the `receiver` contract.

Comment: thanks but it gives the error that member "owner" not found or not visible.

Comment: Kindly look into my problem.

Comment: @zak100 The problem was that the function were referencing the contract `receiver` but it should have used the instance `receiverObj` instead. Take a look at the updated answer, I tested in remix and it should work.